Unable to connect to Eureka - Spring Cloud 2024.0.0 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server
Spring cloud 2024.0.0 Services are not able to register to Eureka. I have tried pretty much every setting that is in the documentation as well as in various threads. Please check below and let me know what could possibly be the issue.
I'm getting this error:
2024-12-13T10:20:24.374+10:30  WARN 17348 --- [API-GATEWAY] [foReplicator-%d] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_API-GATEWAY/host.docker.internal:API-GATEWAY:8085 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:76) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]

Below is my Eureka Server, and it is pretty much running fine on port 8761:
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class EurekaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Eureka server config:
server:
  port: 8761
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
logging:
  level:
    com.netflix.eureka: OFF
    com.netflix.discovery: OFF

And here is the spring cloud gateway:
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class GatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}

The application.yml for the gateway api:
server:
  port: 8085
spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: FACADE-SERVICE
          uri: http://localhost:9300/facade/
          predicates:
            - Path=/FACADE/**
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost

Both my Eureka and Gateway service pom ar on spring cloud 2024.0.0
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2024.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

I also tried this application.yml:
server:
  port: 8085
spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: FACADE-SERVICE
          uri: http://localhost:9300/facade/
          predicates:
            - Path=/FACADE/**
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost


Downgrading the Spring cloud to 2023.0.0 and spring boot to 3.2.0 finally worked.  Seems like the documentation for 2024.0.0 is either not up to date or there is a bug in there. Here's the config that worked:
Eureka pom.xml:
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

Eureka application.yml:
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false

Gateway pom:
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

Gateway application.yml:
server:
  port: 8085
spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: FACADE-SERVICE
          uri: http://localhost:9300/facade/
          predicates:
            - Path=/FACADE/**
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/


Use 2024.0.0-RC1 version
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2024.0.0-RC1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

note: RC1 version is in Spring Milestones repository
<repository>
    <id>spring-milestones</id>
    <name>Spring Milestones</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>

